# Javascript Selecting child element not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook

i m working on adding a FB share button to all my posts.

so i wanted to use the sharer.php? method with all the parameter retrieved from the post.

So my blog structure

```
<div id='postwrapper'>
    <div id='title'>
        hello</a>
    </div>
    <div id='da'>
        <span>Posted on </span>
        <span class='divider'></span>
        <span>By</span>
    </div>
    <div class='post_content'>$row['post'] gud day</div>
    <div id='post_footer'>
        <a href=viewpost.php>Continue reading</a>
        <a href='#' onClick='fbshare(this)'>Insert text or an image here.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript for fbshare function (not complete).

```
function fbshare(fb) {
    var p1 = fb.parentNode;
    var p2 = p1.parentNode;       
    var title = p2.getElementById("title").innerHTML;        
    alert(title);
}
```

Everytime i try this it says **undefined is not a function**

Comment: On what line is the error being thrown? Which code is causing this error message?

Comment: Have you tried putting the function in the `href` attribute instead of putting it in the `onclick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById` is a function of the `document`. Assuming you have more than one post on the page (`id`s must by unique), try using a class instead:

```
<div class='title'>
```

And using `getElementsByClassName`:

```
var title = p2.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AJ9uj/